# JQuery Mobile apply style to newly added elements

Tags: jquery-mobile

In JQuery Mobile, I have a navigation bar like the following:

```
<div id="nav_bar" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a>video</a></li>
        <li><a>music</a></li>
        <li><a>picture</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Say now I want the nav bar to display "some content" only. This is my code:

```
$("#nav_bar ul").html("<li><a>some content</a></li>");
```

But the built-in JQuery Mobile style is not applied to it. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you're replacing the `ul` with? There should be one or more `<li><a>Something</a></li>`. Also, make sure you have the proper classes added.

Comment: @Maqsood like now? I think adding classes manually is not an elegant way for doing this since there are too many classes to add.

Answer (score 0):

When a page is opened, a script runs to add all the necessary classes. Replacing an item does not rerun the script.

I don't think you can do this without adding in the class manually by either specifying the classes in the text/using a variable or the following:

```
$("#nav_bar ul").html('<li><a>some content</a></li>').children('li').addClass('class-one class-two');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nav_bar ul").html("<li><a>some content</a></li>");
```

.html() method destroys ul element and its contents then adds new content.

You should use .append() instead.

```
$("#nav_bar ul").append("<li><a>some content</a></li>");
```

If you actually want to replace the original content.

Target the div and use .html() method

```
$("#nav_bar").html("<ul><li><a>some content</a></li></ul>");​
```